# Javascript - Change image according to image selected

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm using asp.net mvc.

I have two icons/pictures as follows:

```
<div class="gallery-preview-img" id="forest">
                                    <a href="#"><img onclick="changeImage()" src="~/Content/themes/base/images/forest_icon.png"></a>
                                </div>
<div class="gallery-preview-img" id="urban">
                                    <a href="#"><img onclick="changeImage()" src="~/Content/themes/base/images/urban_icon.png"></a>
                                </div>
```

Script:

```
        $(function changeImage() {
        $('#forest').click(function () {
            if (!(document.getElementById('forest').src.match('forestG'))) {
                document.getElementById('forest').src = "~/Content/themes/base/images/forestG.png";
                if (!(document.getElementById('urban').src.match('urban_icon')) {
                    document.getElementById('urban').src = "~/Content/themes/base/images/urban_icon.png";
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('env').value = 'Forest';
        })
        $('#urban').click(function () {
            if (!(document.getElementById('urban').src.match('urbanG')) {
                document.getElementById('urban').src = "~/Content/themes/base/images/urbanG.png";
                if (!(document.getElementById('forest').src != 'forest_icon')) {
                    document.getElementById('forest').src = "~/Content/themes/base/images/forest_icon.png";
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('env').value = 'Urban';
        });
    }
 });
```

However the pictures/icons are not changing. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: where u use the #forest or the #urban ID on your HTML?

Comment: why do you use "$(function changeImage() {" and also the "$('#forest').click(function () {" to check a click? one of them is too much. just use only the jquery click promise. so remove in js the "$(function changeImage() {" and in html the onclick="changeImage()" tag.

Comment: Tried this^ - still with problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to what I believe you are trying to do. I think your approach right now is alot a bit too complicated. Hope this helps

https://jsfiddle.net/stevenkaspar/qs8L20wt/

```
<img onclick='changeImage(event);' src='/path/to/image.png'/>

function changeImage(event){
  document.getElementById('destination').src = event.target.src;
}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to have two icons/images A and B. When A is selected it changes image to C (and ensures B is not D), when B is selected it changes image to D (and ensures A is not C).

Comment: what happens if B is D?

Comment: Imagine you have two icons, and the user is going to select one. Upon selection, the icon selected changes colour(ie pic). Does this clarify?

Comment: No too much. Try looking at my updated jsfiddle. I am using classNames where I think you want to use images. If that doesn't help I am not really sure what you are looking for. Sorry